# ¿Cómo puedo indicar que mb-5 funcione en safari? Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, safari

Espero haberme explicado bien con esta pregunta.

Tengo una web subida a un dominio, dicha web es usada desde distintos navegadores y sistemas operativos.

En un apartado de dicha web, en un formlario tengo un botón para que envíe los datos pero este no es visible desde ordenadores MAC, móviles Iphone, ya que tengo como footer, un footer fijo (fixed).

Mi pregunta es hay alguna solución para este problema especialmente para este sistema operativo, incluyendo su navegador Safari.

Como framework de estilos uso Bootstrap.

Comment: MB-5? Eso es margin-bottom y funciona en todos los navegadores principales https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/margin-bottom#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: Sí pero en Safari no acaba de funcionar correctamente.